# Print statement just before calling a function with a tqdm progress bar results in the print statement being printed after tddm

Tags: python, ipython, tqdm

When working with tqdm for a project, I've noticed that when I use a print statement just before I call a function that has a tqdm progress bar, the print statement is printed somewhere in between the progress bars.

I've noticed that this behaviour only occurs in ipython notebooks, not when run in terminal.

[image: example output in ipython]

[image: example output in terminal]

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

def long_progress():
    for _ in tqdm(range(100)):
        time.sleep(.05)

for i in range(5):
    print("Show parameters of the progress")
    long_progress()
```

This behaviour doesn't break anything, I'm just really curious why it is happening.

I've also noticed that when I use `time.sleep(0.2)` before I call tqdm it's resolved, so it seems like some timing issue.

Edit:
Changed print statement to reflect my goal more precisely

Comment: Did you find its solution

Answer (score 0):

Define the print statement outside the loop i.e

```
print("Lets start long progress")
for i in range(5):
    long_progress()
```

This will call the print before the loop execution.

Comment: I see the confusion, but I actually want to print before each progress bar. In my project before each progress bar is printed the parameters that are used.